# Change response of fetch instead of creating a new one

Tags: javascript

I need to fetch a file and forward the response of the fetch to another function but in between I need to change the body. The code I came up is this:

```
    const fetchResponse = await fetch(event.request);

    const text_of_response = await fetchResponse.text();
    text_of_response = text_of_response .replace("MARCADOR1","ON-LINE");
    
    return fetchResponse;
```

Of course the code above will not work because I changed the response text in a variable. How do I put it back in the original response?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to change the response itself. Why don't you just `return text_of_response`?

Comment: It is so broken I'm not sure what is a typo and what isn't. If you want to use **text_of_response** why don't you return that?

Comment: Are you just concerned with the body of the response?  What does the full body show and what are you trying to change specifically?

Comment: I need to return the entire response to another function (that I cant control). The other functions wants the entire response, not only the body. I discovered the fetch has a `clone` method but I cant find a way to change the body

Comment: Do you mean *intercepting* the fetch call, change the body, and forward the response to the function that is making the actual fetch call?

Comment: If you want the entire response and to modify the body you can return an object `return {fetchResponse,text_of_response}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a copy of the response manually:

```js
(async () => {
  
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  const text = await response.text();
  
  
  // change your text as you like
  const posts = JSON.parse(text);
  const transformed = posts.map(post => post.body).join(' ');
  
  const transformedResponse = new Response(transformed, {
    status: response.status,
    statusText: response.statusText,
    headers: Object.fromEntries(response.headers.entries())
  });
  
  console.log(await transformedResponse.text());

})();
```